# Bridged network on VirtualBox with Lubuntu

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge, lubuntu

I have imported an Ubuntu system (Lubuntu) in VirtualBox and setted Bridged network in the settings of Virtual Machine but it can't still connect to web.
If I try to ping my router it returns "Host Unreachable" but in his ARP cache (of router) the ip of vm appears.
With NAT settings instead it works fine.. Can anyone help me?
Another thing to note is that in ARP cache of router the MAC address of the virtual system is same as the host but if I use "ip a" command (in vm) the MAC is different.
My host system is Windows 8.1

Comment: Is your host adapter WiFi or hard wired? There are known issues with WiFi and bridge mode, you need to create a Host Only network, this question has been asked and answered many times... http://christophermaier.name/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox/

Comment: If i set up a Host Only network i could be able to communicate with other devices in my lan and connect to internet?